# Overdispersion in logistic regression --- Use beta-binomial?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, overdispersion, beta-binomial-distribution

I have some cell counts obtained via flow cytometry - simply put, I have the amount of positive cells (Successes) from the overall number of cells (Successes + Failures).  Based on the data structure, I thought to use a classic binomial/logistic regression.

After performing the regression, using packages such as `DHarma`, I realized that the model is overdispersed. One of the things I've read is that you can use beta-binomial regression to solve some overdispersion problems.

What I would like to know is:

1. Is it reasonable to look for other distribution families (e.g. beta-binomial or quasibinomial) when overdispersion occurs? and
2. Is beta-binomial a good idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Could you give some more details? Sample size, which predictors?  --- but, yes, beta-binomial could be a good solution. Other possibilities quasi-binomial or --- In the side panel there is a section **Related**, look through it, some of the posts there will be helpful!

Comment: Hey @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks for your response!
Regarding your questions:
1) The predictors are TimePoint (3 categories) and Treatment (only 2 categories). Right now, we have around ~50 but, we are working on repeating the experiment (and maybe add this as a random effect but, that something to think about down the line).

2) Thanks for the suggestion regarding the related section!!